# Pic32_MZEF_Curiosity_v2: USB Device only (Audio + CDC) Not Working

Tags: android, audio, usb, cdc, pic32

This is the first time for me in a USB environment hence any input is highly appreciated.

**My Setup:**

-Pic32 ME EF curiosity v2 board + AK4954 Codec Module attached to mikro Bus 2 using Mplab x 5V5 IDE under Harmony 3

-My current project code/ example codes / Wireshark data [WIP here](https://artagroup-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/gokulnath_arcot-ramanandan_comufrance_com/Emj0e83migJKtBB1HuigTnYBaQs43XVFncq0XXD7m9ZTtA?e=AZuSDN)

-default microchip audio & cdc examples are functional

**Desired result:(USB Device mode only)**

I would like to emulate USB headphones (Audio playing from YT video on android phone) + CDC (custom data sent to serial USB terminal app on Android upon button press)

**My progress:**

I've used the default Microchip functional audio example & integrated the CDC example into it.
My USB composite device is enumerated correctly into my PC (device manager) & then I'm receiving

```
“This device cannot start. (Code 10)” on windows I use a software named “UsbTreeView” I checked it and It’s telling me like this：
 
----------------- Device Qualifier Descriptor -----------------
Error : ERROR_GEN_FAILURE
```

if I’ve understood the USB concept well -> The IAD(Interface
association descriptor) is also declared accurately. but I'm having a
doubt on configuration descriptors.

> In windows, it shows The com port(CDC is enumerated correctly but the
> audio is in an error state) but when I tried using putty no data is
> flowing through but I could see the data sent from the board on
> Wireshark upon button press.

I've also attached the Wireshark log as when I press the button I can see the interrupt + data sent from the device to the host. (but with this error:IRP USBD_STATUS: USBD_STATUS_CANCELED (0xc0010000))

> I then connected this to my android phone & the audio is functional &
> CDC terminal station "control transfer failed"

> I also connected this to UBUNTU PC & the audio is functional properly
> & CDC terminal TTYACM0 "Terminal open failed " by the app "Screen"

Device Descriptors

```
Information for device USB Headset PIC32MZEF AUD + CDC (VID=0x04D8 PID=0x0065):

------------------------------
Connection Information:
------------------------------
Device current bus speed: FullSpeed
Device supports USB 1.1 specification
Device supports USB 2.0 specification
Device address: 0x001A
Current configuration value: 0x01
Number of open pipes: 3


------------------------------
Device Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x12    bLength
0x01    bDescriptorType
0x0200  bcdUSB
0x00    bDeviceClass      
0x00    bDeviceSubClass   
0x00    bDeviceProtocol   
0x40    bMaxPacketSize0   (64 bytes)
0x04D8  idVendor
0x0065  idProduct
0x0100  bcdDevice
0x01    iManufacturer   "Microchip Technology Inc."
0x02    iProduct        "USB Headset PIC32MZEF AUD + CDC"
0x03    iSerialNumber   "12345678999"
0x01    bNumConfigurations


-------------------------
Configuration Descriptor:
-------------------------
0x09    bLength
0x02    bDescriptorType
0x012C  wTotalLength   (300 bytes)
0x05    bNumInterfaces
0x01    bConfigurationValue
0x00    iConfiguration
0xC0    bmAttributes   (Self-powered Device)
0x32    bMaxPower      (100 mA)

Interface Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x09    bLength
0x04    bDescriptorType
0x00    bInterfaceNumber
0x00    bAlternateSetting
0x00    bNumEndPoints
0x01    bInterfaceClass      (Audio Device Class)
0x01    bInterfaceSubClass   (Audio Control Interface)
0x00    bInterfaceProtocol   (Audio Protocol undefined)
0x00    iInterface

AC Interface Header Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x0A    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x01    bDescriptorSubtype
0x0100  bcdADC
0x0064  wTotalLength   (100 bytes)
0x02    bInCollection
0x01    baInterfaceNr(1)
0x02    baInterfaceNr(2)

AC Input Terminal Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x0C    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x02    bDescriptorSubtype
0x01    bTerminalID
0x0101  wTerminalType   (USB Streaming)
0x00    bAssocTerminal
0x02    bNrChannels   (2 channels)
0x0003  wChannelConfig
0x00    iChannelNames
0x00    iTerminal

AC Input Terminal Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x0C    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x02    bDescriptorSubtype
0x04    bTerminalID
0x0201  wTerminalType   (Microphone)
0x00    bAssocTerminal
0x01    bNrChannels   (1 channels)
0x0004  wChannelConfig
0x00    iChannelNames
0x00    iTerminal

AC Feature Unit Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x0D    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x06    bDescriptorSubtype
0x02    bUnitID
0x08    bSourceID
0x02    bControlSize
bmaControls: 
 0x01   Channel(0) - Mute
 0x00   Channel(1)
 0x00   Channel(2)
0x00    iFeature


AC Feature Unit Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x0B    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x06    bDescriptorSubtype
0x05    bUnitID
0x04    bSourceID
0x02    bControlSize
bmaControls: 
 0x01   Channel(0) - Mute
 0x00   Channel(1)
0x00    iFeature


AC Feature Unit Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x0B    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x06    bDescriptorSubtype
0x07    bUnitID
0x04    bSourceID
0x02    bControlSize
bmaControls: 
 0x01   Channel(0) - Mute
 0x00   Channel(1)
0x00    iFeature


AC Mixer Unit Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x0D    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x04    bDescriptorSubtype
0x08    bUnitID
0x02    bBrInPins
0x01    baSourceID(1)
0x07    baSourceID(2)
0x02    bNrChannels
0x0003  wChannelConfig
0x00    iChannelNames
bmControls:
0x00 
0x00    iMixer

AC Output Terminal Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x09    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x03    bDescriptorSubtype
0x03    bTerminalID
0x0302  wTerminalType   (Headphones)
0x00    bAssocTerminal
0x02    bSourceID
0x00    iTerminal

AC Output Terminal Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x09    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x03    bDescriptorSubtype
0x06    bTerminalID
0x0101  wTerminalType   (USB Streaming)
0x00    bAssocTerminal
0x05    bSourceID
0x00    iTerminal

Interface Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x09    bLength
0x04    bDescriptorType
0x01    bInterfaceNumber
0x00    bAlternateSetting
0x00    bNumEndPoints
0x01    bInterfaceClass      (Audio Device Class)
0x02    bInterfaceSubClass   (Audio Streaming Interface)
0x00    bInterfaceProtocol   (Audio Protocol undefined)
0x00    iInterface

Interface Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x09    bLength
0x04    bDescriptorType
0x01    bInterfaceNumber
0x01    bAlternateSetting
0x01    bNumEndPoints
0x01    bInterfaceClass      (Audio Device Class)
0x02    bInterfaceSubClass   (Audio Streaming Interface)
0x00    bInterfaceProtocol   (Audio Protocol undefined)
0x00    iInterface

AS Interface Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x07    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x01    bDescriptorSubtype
0x01    bTerminalLink
0x01    bDelay
0x0001  wFormatTag   (PCM)

AS Format Type 1 Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x11    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x02    bDescriptorSubtype
0x01    bFormatType   (FORMAT_TYPE_1)
0x02    bNrChannels   (2 channels)
0x02    bSubframeSize
0x10    bBitResolution   (16 bits per sample)
0x03    bSamFreqType   (Discrete sampling frequencies)
0x003E80    tSamFreq(1)   (16000 Hz)
0x007D00    tSamFreq(2)   (32000 Hz)
0x00BB80    tSamFreq(3)   (48000 Hz)

Endpoint Descriptor (Audio/MIDI 1.0):
------------------------------
0x09    bLength
0x05    bDescriptorType
0x01    bEndpointAddress  (OUT endpoint 1)
0x09    bmAttributes      (Transfer: Isochronous / Synch: Adaptive / Usage: Data)
0x00C0  wMaxPacketSize    (1 x 192 bytes)
0x01    bInterval         (1 frames)
0x00    bRefresh
0x00    bSynchAddress

AS Isochronous Data Endpoint Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x07    bLength
0x25    bDescriptorType
0x01    bDescriptorSubtype
0x01    bmAttributes   (Sampling Frequency)
0x00    bLockDelayUnits   (undefined)
0x0000  wLockDelay

Interface Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x09    bLength
0x04    bDescriptorType
0x02    bInterfaceNumber
0x00    bAlternateSetting
0x00    bNumEndPoints
0x01    bInterfaceClass      (Audio Device Class)
0x02    bInterfaceSubClass   (Audio Streaming Interface)
0x00    bInterfaceProtocol   (Audio Protocol undefined)
0x00    iInterface

Interface Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x09    bLength
0x04    bDescriptorType
0x02    bInterfaceNumber
0x01    bAlternateSetting
0x01    bNumEndPoints
0x01    bInterfaceClass      (Audio Device Class)
0x02    bInterfaceSubClass   (Audio Streaming Interface)
0x00    bInterfaceProtocol   (Audio Protocol undefined)
0x00    iInterface

AS Interface Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x07    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x01    bDescriptorSubtype
0x06    bTerminalLink
0x00    bDelay
0x0001  wFormatTag   (PCM)

AS Format Type 1 Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x11    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x02    bDescriptorSubtype
0x01    bFormatType   (FORMAT_TYPE_1)
0x01    bNrChannels   (1 channels)
0x02    bSubframeSize
0x10    bBitResolution   (16 bits per sample)
0x03    bSamFreqType   (Discrete sampling frequencies)
0x003E80    tSamFreq(1)   (16000 Hz)
0x007D00    tSamFreq(2)   (32000 Hz)
0x00BB80    tSamFreq(3)   (48000 Hz)

Endpoint Descriptor (Audio/MIDI 1.0):
------------------------------
0x09    bLength
0x05    bDescriptorType
0x82    bEndpointAddress  (IN endpoint 2)
0x0D    bmAttributes      (Transfer: Isochronous / Synch: Synchronous / Usage: Data)
0x0060  wMaxPacketSize    (1 x 96 bytes)
0x01    bInterval         (1 frames)
0x00    bRefresh
0x00    bSynchAddress

AS Isochronous Data Endpoint Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x07    bLength
0x25    bDescriptorType
0x01    bDescriptorSubtype
0x01    bmAttributes   (Sampling Frequency)
0x00    bLockDelayUnits   (undefined)
0x0000  wLockDelay

Interface Association Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x08    bLength
0x0B    bDescriptorType
0x03    bFirstInterface
0x02    bInterfaceCount
0x02    bFunctionClass      (Communication Device Class)
0x02    bFunctionSubClass   (Abstract Control Model - ACM)
0x01    bFunctionProtocol   (ITU-T V.250)
0x00    iFunction

Interface Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x09    bLength
0x04    bDescriptorType
0x03    bInterfaceNumber
0x00    bAlternateSetting
0x01    bNumEndPoints
0x02    bInterfaceClass      (Communication Device Class)
0x02    bInterfaceSubClass   (Abstract Control Model - ACM)
0x01    bInterfaceProtocol   (ITU-T V.250)
0x00    iInterface

CDC Header Functional Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x05    bFunctionalLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x00    bDescriptorSubtype
0x0120  bcdCDC

CDC Abstract Control Management Functional Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x04    bFunctionalLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x02    bDescriptorSubtype
0x02    bmCapabilities

CDC Union Functional Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x05    bFunctionalLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x06    bDescriptorSubtype
0x03    bControlInterface
0x04    bSubordinateInterface(0)

CDC Call Management Functional Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x05    bFunctionalLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x01    bDescriptorSubtype
0x00    bmCapabilities
0x04    bDataInterface

Endpoint Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x07    bLength
0x05    bDescriptorType
0x83    bEndpointAddress  (IN endpoint 3)
0x03    bmAttributes      (Transfer: Interrupt / Synch: None / Usage: Data)
0x0010  wMaxPacketSize    (1 x 16 bytes)
0x02    bInterval         (2 frames)

Interface Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x09    bLength
0x04    bDescriptorType
0x04    bInterfaceNumber
0x00    bAlternateSetting
0x02    bNumEndPoints
0x0A    bInterfaceClass      (CDC Data)
0x00    bInterfaceSubClass   
0x00    bInterfaceProtocol   
0x00    iInterface

Endpoint Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x07    bLength
0x05    bDescriptorType
0x04    bEndpointAddress  (OUT endpoint 4)
0x02    bmAttributes      (Transfer: Bulk / Synch: None / Usage: Data)
0x0040  wMaxPacketSize    (64 bytes)
0x00    bInterval         

Endpoint Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x07    bLength
0x05    bDescriptorType
0x84    bEndpointAddress  (IN endpoint 4)
0x02    bmAttributes      (Transfer: Bulk / Synch: None / Usage: Data)
0x0040  wMaxPacketSize    (64 bytes)
0x00    bInterval         

Microsoft OS Descriptor is not available. Error code: 0x0000001F


--------------------------------
String Descriptor Table
--------------------------------
Index  LANGID  String
0x00   0x0000  0x0409 
0x01   0x0409  "Microchip Technology Inc."
0x02   0x0409  "USB Headset PIC32MZEF AUD + CDC"
0x03   0x0409  "12345678999"

------------------------------

Connection path for device: 
USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller
Root Hub
Generic USB Hub
Generic USB Hub
USB Headset PIC32MZEF AUD + CDC (VID=0x04D8 PID=0x0065) Port: 1

Running on: Windows 10 or greater (Build Version 19044)

Brought to you by TDD v2.17.0, Feb 23 2021, 14:04:02
```

Please let me know the possible solutions & which area should I focus more on?

Thanks for your time. I really appreciate it

Have a good day